# Adding elements to an array in C

Tags: c, arrays, loops, scanf, element

I have an assignment to create a grade book with student names and grades and I'm stuck where it asks me to add a new student. STUDNO is where the program only allows 75 students with a NAMELENGTH of 40.

So I have written a for loop to search through the array and I have no errors or warnings yet the program skips over the scanf function where it asks for name input.

Here is the code:

```
    #define STUDNO 75
#define NAMELENGTH 40

void super(int studNo, char name [STUDNO][NAMELENGTH],
     int studMark1[STUDNO], int studMark2[STUDNO],
     int studMark3[STUDNO], int pinNo[][3])
{
    int i;
    char newName;
    int newNo;

    printf("\n      Add New Student\n");
    printf("\nPlease enter a student number: \n");
    scanf("%d", &newNo);
    printf("Please enter the student name:\n");
    scanf("%[^\n]", &newName);
    for(i = studNo-1; i >= newNo; i--)
    {
        name[STUDNO+1][NAMELENGTH]=name[STUDNO][NAMELENGTH];
    }
    name[newNo][NAMELENGTH] = newName;
```

Comment: Have you already studied the `struct` C keyword? If yes, then your approach is wrong. If no, then you should definitely study `struct` first.

Comment: Also study the chapter dealing with strings in your beginner's C text book, especially the `strcpy` function. You cannot assign strings with `=`.

Comment: Thank you for a response, Jabberwocky. I haven't got as far as using struct yet and just have to make-do with the tools I have for now which are quite basic. I have actually managed to get a new element (name) added to the array. I'm still having problems getting it to be displayed but I am trying to work it out by passing data from one function to another.

Answer (score 0):

This problem is very common. When the last thing printed to the console counts as a valid input for your scanf function, it'll read that as the input or not read anything at all, not letting the user put an input into the code. I can't get anymore technical than that because I'm not 100% sure what's happening in the scanf funtion that would cause this but to fix it, all you have to do is include the last thing you printed to the console. Your code would look like this.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
  char newName;
  int newNo;

  printf("\nPlease enter a student number: \n");
  scanf("%d", &newNo);
  printf("Please enter the student name:\n");
  scanf("\n%[^\n]", &newName);
  printf("\n%c\n",newName); //To check if it's working
  return 0;
}
```

When I ran this, I noticed that this only gets you the first letter of your input so if you want the entire string, you would write the code like this.

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define NAMELENGTH 40
int main(void) {
  char newName[NAMELENGTH];
  int newNo;

  printf("\nPlease enter a student number: \n");
  scanf("%d", &newNo);
  printf("Please enter the student name:\n");
  scanf("\n%[^\n]", newName);
  printf("\n%s\n",newName); //To check if it's working
  return 0;
}
```

The code above can give you the following output:

Please enter a student number:

40

Please enter the student name:

anhtz

anhtz

Comment: Hi LoganMacMonkey, thanks for the response. I have set up the program quite similarly to your example and it does work just fine. I can see the names I have input in one function displayed in full in another. I am just having trouble with adding new names into the array.

Comment: I noticed that you never used i in your for loop.  you should replace STUDNO with i within your for loop.

Comment: It seems to be working but it is storing the name in some random place in memory, the slot in the array has been allocated for it but it is just displaying random symbols instead of the name.